# What's wrong with my Laravel 5.5 save() method?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.5, I want to do basic form input where is only one field->"email". I am using Eloquent, model to interact with database for these subscriber inputs. When the controller method is called, this error follows:

> FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Call to a member function save() on
>   string

The thing is I am using exactly the same solution for other form I've got in my application (contact form). That's the reason why I am pretty sure, that namespacing, models or other stuff I written well.

This is my code:

**SubsController.php**

```
class SubsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $subscriber = new Subscriber;
        $subscriber=$request->input('email');
        $subscriber->save();
        return redirect()->to(route('homepage'));
    }
}
```

Comment: you're calling `save` on a string because you've just assigned `$request->input('email')` into `$subscriber`

Comment: it should be like $subscriber->email = $request->input('email');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this line, you just assigned a string value to your `$subscriber` variable

```
$subscriber =$request->input('email');
```

The correct way is

```
public function store(Request $request) { 
    $subscriber = new Subscriber;
    $subscriber->email =$request->input('email'); 
    $subscriber->save(); 
    return redirect()->to(route('homepage')); 
}
```

Comment: Oh my god! So embarrasing to mistake like this! It was just because i "overseen" that (4am here working all night)...thank you so much.

Comment: We all do that once in a while. Haha

Comment: @OndOne Consider having a good sleep and starting fresh in the morning. This sort of mistake is exactly why all-nighters tend to be unproductive - sometimes you're *worse* off after one.

Comment: Thanks again guys, take care.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

```
$subscriber = new Subscriber;  
$subscriber->email = $request->input('email');       
$subscriber->save();  
return redirect()->to(route('homepage'));
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution is

```
public function store() { 
    $data = request()->validate('email');
    Subscriber::create($data);
    return redirect()->route('homepage'); 
}
```